# How to change iframe source by sending a message

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have looked at various documentation and similar questions on here, but cannot seem to find the particular solution. Apologies if I have missed anything obvious or have repeated this question!

I am working on an html page which hosts an iframe and will change depending upon situation. The iframe source is not changing based on message send. I did some test run and the iframe source doesn't seem to be updating.

The iframe code is as follows:

```
<!--HTTPS only...-->
<style>
    iframe 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.735);
        -moz-transform-scale(.65);
        clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 10px 10px 2px 2px);
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="iframe-wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.test1.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <script>
    
           window.onmessage = function(event)
            {
                console.log(event.data)
                frameObj.src = event.data;
            };
        </script>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Whilst I am sending the message as follows:

```
export function button17_click(event) 
{
  let url = "https://www.test4.com/"
  console.log("postMessage should get triggered")
  $w("#html1").postMessage(url);
    $w("#html1").onMessage((event) =>
    {

        if (event.data.type === 'ready')
        {
            $w("#html1").postMessage(url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this code even run? `frameObj.src = event.data;`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski The intial source `src="https://www.test1.com/" ` does indeed fire but onMessage sent it doesn't change the source

Comment: I'm asking if you placed a console log in the handler to debug it somehow or you just straight posted a question here without debugging?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski oh yes indeed I did. The button does print a message that it is printing, the code is cleaned without logs. It is placed in the button onClick event. Edited code to reflect this.

Comment: I know not all of your code is here, but does `frameObj` return your `<iframe>`? What if you `console.log(frameObj.src)` before and after you attempt to set the **src**? Do those logged values change at all or both still return the original **src**?